# What is the average age of daily riders?

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

Have a simple problem I am trying to solve with the `tidyverse`, particularly `dplyr` (I believe this is the appropriate function).

What is the average age of daily riders?

There is a `data.frame` named `Bike` and there are two columns of data including `cyc_freq` which includes the `Daily` observation and another column of data entitled `age` which contains the different ages.

I am attempting to write a script that returns the average `age` of those who ride their bikes `Daily`. I was able to solve the problem but feel like my solution was inefficient.

Is there a simpler way to achieve my answer using `dplyr`?

```
bavg <- filter(BikeData, cyc_freq == "Daily", age)
mean(bavg$age)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done within `summarise` itself without the need to have another step with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
BikeData %>%
         summarise(Mean = mean(age[cyc_freq == "Daily"]))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
with(BikeData, mean(age[cyc_freq == "Daily"]))
```